# Is there a seamless solution for submitting plugins to wordpress.org SVN and GitHub?

Tags: svn, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How-to: push a GitHub repo to the wordpress plugin servers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/how-to-push-a-github-repo-to-the-wordpress-plugin-servers)

I love WordPress, but I also love GitHub. Would love to know if there is a seamless solution to using both SVN and GitHub for plugin development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wordpress plugin repo does not have any API as far as I can tell for push and pull hooks from a 3rd party service like github.

Right now the solutions are hacky at best and require you to use git as a middle man (on your computer) and also deal with SVN's use of tags/trunk/branch which git doesn't like very much.

It's not very fun or seemless, more along the lines of "can I actually do this", at least for the moment.
http://teleogistic.net/2011/05/revisiting-git-github-and-the-wordpress-org-plugin-repository/
http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/developing-on-wordpress-using-git/